# Arduino serial connection

Tags: c++, arduino

I need to make a serial connection between my computer and my arduino.  I found a class which makes the serial connection and works without any error.  I have written my code in arduino(reading from port 2 to arduino and writing it to an output and receiving a character from C++) which is:

```
 int PButton=2;
 int Led=13;
 unsigned long start,finished,elapsed;


 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); //begins the Serial Connection.
 pinMode(PButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(Led,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(Led,LOW);
 Serial.println("Is the video already started? ""y/n""...\n");
 start=millis();

}

 void loop() {


 if(Serial.available()>0){
 char letter=Serial.read();
 if(letter=='y'){
   digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
   Serial.println("The video is started!\n");

  }
  else if(letter=='n'){
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    Serial.println("The Video is still not started! \n");  
  }
  else
  Serial.println("Enter a valid Answer please!\n");

}

int buttonState=digitalRead(PButton);  //read the input pin
if(buttonState==LOW){ 
    Serial.println(" the pushbutton is  pressed!");
    finished=millis();
    elapsed=finished-start;
    Serial.print(elapsed);
     } 


}
```

The code works well as a standalone and it makes the correct output in serial monitor.  The problem is that i am not very experienced in C++ and I am confused how to write the main function to read and write to and from C++ to arduino and vice versa.  I found some codes in stackoverflow but I cant adjust them to my need.

This is my C++ code (I already have the serial connection class). I am not sure which line to comment out and if it is logical at all!

```
// SerialCommunication.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die 
Konsolenanwendung.
//This code snippet will help you to read data from arduino
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "SerialPort.h"


//using namespace std;
//using std::cin;
//using std::cout;
//using std::endl;

//String for getting the Output from Arduino
char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];

//Portname must contain these backslashes
char *port_name = "\\\\.\\COM5";

//const unsigned int bufSize =255;

//String for incoming data
char incomingData[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];


int main()
 {
 SerialPort arduino(port_name);
 if (arduino.isConnected())
    std::cout << "Connection Established" << std::endl;
 else
    std::cout << "ERROR, check port!";

 while (arduino.isConnected()) {
    //std::cout << "Is the video Started?Yes or No: \n";
    //std::string input_string = "Blabla\n";
    char answer;
    std::cin >> answer;
    //Writing answer to arduino
    arduino.writeSerialPort( (answer* ), MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
    //Getting reply from arduino
    arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
    //printing the output
    puts(output);

}

/*while (arduino.isConnected()) {
    //Check if data has been read or not
    int read_result = arduino.readSerialPort(incomingData, bufSize);
    //prints out data
    puts(incomingData);
    //wait a bit
    Sleep(10);
}*/
}
```

Comment: I’m trying to understand what it is you are trying to achieve with this. You want to ready data from the arduino and write data to it?

Comment: Is your Computer code showing "Connection Established"< or "ERROR, check port!". Ideally, you are expected to state this as a part of the question.

Comment: @ Sailanarmo The whole Senario is that : There is a Button connected to the Arduino and video running at PC. The task is to send a character from C++ to Arduino, when the video is started. When Arduino receives the y Character from C++, arduino starts countng the time till the user pushes the button.when the user pushes the button, Arduino sends a signal back to c++ that the user has done so and the elapsed time also. I have difficulty understanding how could C++ understand this process.

Comment: @ Nitro The C++ code is a ready code which returns errors weil compiling. When i ccoment first while()  and uncomment second while() it used to work! so it means there is a serial connection stablished correctly and i recieve the output of arduino in my C++.but i have difficulty sending data back due to lack of programming skill

Comment: @SaraM so right now you have confirmation that the arduino can send information to the C++ side of things. But in your C++ code, you cannot see the output to the Arduino. Correct?

Comment: @ Sailanarmo i am not sure if i understand your comment correctly.First i expect my program to be compiled without errors and second see the output from C++ to Arduino.

Comment: @SaraM will you go to [my website](https://sailanarmo.github.io/) and send me an email? I need to understand the problem a bit more and I don't think this is the best place to get this solved for you.